# Sort an Array in php where values are get using functions

Tags: php, magento

i have an array

```
$person
```

containing an `$id` and `$name`, further its `$id` can be get by

```
getpersonId()
```

and `$name` can be get by

```
getpersonName()
```

function,
i want to sort this array using name as key value,
how can we sort this using php.

Comment: Show us the actual array and functions so we can help you.

Comment: usort, try it out, if it doesn`t work come back

Comment: @KA_lin it's doesn't work

Comment: @Luna Some code perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
 function sort_by_name($a, $b) {
   return   strcmp($a->getpersonName(),$b->getpersonName());
}

usort($person, 'sort_by_name');
```

you can replace `$a->getpersonName()` by whatever you are using to access $name.